# Как передавать cookie между файлами в библиотеке Ratchet websocket

Tags: php, функции, websocket, ratchet, realtime

Кто работал с данной библиотекой - знает, куки браузера можно получить только при событие onOpen доступном в chat.php  только там можно получить данные кук клиента,  мне надо передать их в loserver.php.. Тк функцию нельзя вызвать самостоятельно, вероятнее данные кук доступны по некой ссылке в остальных частях файла ( после получения, они ведь кудат сохраняются? Или как иначе передать их в другие части программы?)

Comment: Повтор https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/875886/Как-можно-получить-cookie-в-loserver-в-библиотеке-ratchet-websockets

Comment: Ибо там я ответа не получил, учись читать...

Comment: Функцию нельзя самостоятельно запустить, значит значение кудат должно сохранятся...